# How do I add an existing person to a group in the Mac Address Book using pyobjc?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pyobjc

Can anyone give me any guidance as to how I can add an existing person to a group in the Mac Address Book using pyobjc?
So far I have managed to get a list of the members of each group.

Answer (score 0):

[The AddressBook framework documentation on Apple's developer website](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/ManagingGroups.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001022-BABHHIHC) describes how you do so. You basically use the groups "addMember_" method to add a new member to a group.

Comment: Thanks Ronald
Here is a link to the code just in case
https://github.com/orotau/soul_ab/blob/master/ab_utilities.py